# The meaning of symbols related to positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I have encountered two undefined symbols when reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.08334.pdf):

Given two real and positive semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$ with the same size,

1. the first relation is written as
   $$A \npreceq B, $$
   which appears on the top of Page $10$.

Does it mean that $(B-A)$ is not positive semidefinite, i.e., the minimal eigenvalue of $(B-A)$ is negative?

2. another relation is written as
   $$
   A  \succsim B
   ,$$
   which appears on the top of Page 9, in the text after equation (2.8).

Is this symbol somehow related to matrix similarity?

Could you help me find a reference where these symbols are clearly defined?

Comment: Answer to 1 is yes. I dunno about 2 without looking at it.

Comment: $X \gtrsim Y$ usually means $X>cY$ for some constant $c$, so perhaps there's something analogous going on here.

Comment: For 1 to be true you need to explicitly require that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric.  There are conflicting definitions of positive semi definite over reals unfortunately.  If symmetry is not required, e.g. consider $(B-A)= $the $2\times 2$ non-zero strictly upper triangular matrix...

Comment: I think that positive semidefiniteness is defined for symmetric matrices, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix

Comment: one definition of positive semidefiniteness over $\mathbb R$ is $\mathbf x^T A \mathbf x \geq 0$ for all $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$; the other definition is that combined with the requirement that $A=A^T$.  These are two distinct definitions that are by no means equivalent.